# ajax loader gif setinterval

Tags: jquery, ajax, setinterval, loader

I am trying to show the loading image for 3 seconds then load in the ajax data. So iv tried adding this is the before function but its not working, its loading fast, i need it so the loader image will show for 3 seconds

here is my js

```
$.ajax({
        url: "ajax/change_skin.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: {skin:skin},
        before:function(){
            setInterval(function(){
                $('#loader').show();
            }, 3000);
        },
        complete:function(){
            $('#loader').hide();
        },
        success:function(data){
            console.log(date);
        }
    });
```

Comment: So you want the loader to show for *at least 3 seconds*... If the load is longer show it longer?

Comment: Why would you make the user wait 3 extra seconds just to see your spinning image. (That's not how a spinner is used)

Comment: Have added an alternative that should provide what you wanted (min 3 second spinner during load, but not delay the load).

Answer (score 2):

Show the loader before you do the ajax call.

```js
$("#loader").show();

setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/change_skin.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: {skin:skin},
        complete:function(){
            $('#loader').hide();
        },
        success:function(data){
            console.log(date);
        }
    });
}, 3000);
```

---

**Edit**: I would avoid making users wait any amount of time to see your spinner/loader animation before actually making the ajax call.

Spinners are made to be used to represent actual loading and processing.  In this case, you're falsly representing the speed at which you can handle requests and projecting your slow speeds onto the user.

The way you *should* do this is:

```js
$("#loader").show();

$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/change_skin.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {skin:skin},
    complete:function(){
        $('#loader').hide();
    },
    success:function(data){
        console.log(date);
    }
});
```

Comment: You are just delaying the load with setTimeout. That is a terrible option. @Control Freak: Not they way they have it now!

Comment: You're right.  I wouldn't do this for my own projects.  Since OP wants to make users watch for three seconds, then this is how you would do it.

Comment: @aelieo there is no reason to make the user wait 3 extra seconds for an ajax load. Please explain that to OP they might not understand it's pointless to do this.

Comment: @ControlFreak I edited my answer to reflect how it should be done.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Have added an alternative that does not delay the load, but still gives a min 3 seconds for the spinner as required.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to add an unnecessary 3 second delay to the load (only to the spinner) use the ajax deferred result:

```
// Show the spinner
$("#loader").show();

// Do the ajax load
var deferred = $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/change_skin.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {skin:skin},
    success:function(data){
        console.log(date);
    }
});

// Hide after 3 seconds... and then only if/when ajax completes
setTimeout(function() {
    deferred.then(function(){
       $('#loader').hide();
    });
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your doing it the wrong way. You should do it like this:

```
$('#loader').show();
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/change_skin.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {skin:skin},
        complete:function(){
           $('#loader').hide();
        },
        success:function(data){
            console.log(date);
        }
    });
}, 3000);
```

SetInterval will make every code inside run after the interval specified.

Comment: Again you are delaying the load 3 seconds for no good reason. See alternative using ajax deferred value.